# Postgresql - exclude some results from SELECT

Tags: c++, postgresql

I have a table called "friendship" which columns are like this:

|from|to|status| where "from" and "to" are referenced to a username and "status" is 'a' for accepted, 'd' is for denied and 'p' is for pending.

I would like to select all friends from a user and put them in a separate column.. is it possible?

To know all user friends I did something like this:

```
SELECT to,from,status FROM friendship 
WHERE to = 'john' AND status = 'a'
OR from = 'john' AND status = 'a'
```

Now I need someway to get all names except for 'john' and put them in a separate collumn..

I'm also doing this with c++.. so is there any way I can use PQgetvalue to help me achieve this?

Comment: So, you want to show all that have accepted friend requests, either from John or to John, and show the "other" as a separate column?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` statement:

```
select case
       when "to" = 'john' then "from"
       else "to"
       end as friend
from   friendship
where  status = 'a'
and    ("from" = 'john' or "to" = 'john')
```

Or a `union all` (or `union`, if this yields dups):

```
select "to" as friend
from   friendship
where  status = 'a'
and    "from" = 'john'
union all
select "from" as friend
from   friendship
where  status = 'a'
and    "to" = 'john'
```

As a side note, "from" is a terrible column name... (It's a reserved word.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION operator

```
SELECT "to" as name FROM "friendship"
WHERE "from" = "john" AND "status" = 'a'
UNION
SELECT "from" as name FROM "friendship"
WHERE "to" = 'john' AND "status" = 'a';
```

Comment: Note that backticks aren't valid PostgresSQL syntax; PostgreSQL uses ANSI quoting (`"identifier"` not \``identifier`\`).